# How to upgrade Bitcoin Core Version on Raspberry PI?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I want to upgrade my Bitcoin core version to latest release `0.16.1`. The release docs say `just copy over bitcoind/bitcoin-qt (on Linux)`. What does that mean? what to copy? Copying from where to where?

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.16.1.md#how-to-upgrade

Comment: Would you edit your question to include a link to the document where you find this instruction ?

Comment: added docs link

Answer (score 1):

They are referring to executable binary files, either the *bitcoind* daemon or the *bitcoin-qt* GUI app.

The page with download links is https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.16.1/

The only link for ARM (Raspberry Pi processor) is https://bitcoincore.org/bin/bitcoin-core-0.16.1/bitcoin-0.16.1-arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz and expanding it

```
$ tar -xf bitcoin-0.16.1-arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.gz
```

I find these directories:

```
~/bitcoin-0.16.1$ ll
bin/
include/
lib/
share/

~/bitcoin-0.16.1$ cd bin
~/bitcoin-0.16.1/bin$ ll

bitcoin-cli*
bitcoind*
bitcoin-tx*
test_bitcoin*
```

I don't find a *bitcoin-qt* GUI version; perhaps they have not compiled one yet. But you can certainly use the command-line versions, bitcoind, bitcoin-cli and bitcoin-tx.

The place to put them is where they will be found from anywhere, for example, `/usr/local/bin`   or `/usr/bin`.